# Change login password if already logged in

Tags: password, login

I'm trying to reset my forgotten login password. Most of the other questions I've seen are about not even being able to login. However I setup "start without login" so I can get into the System Preferences etc. I just can't update my PW since I can't remember my old one. Is there anything I can do (other than what I'd do if I couldn't even login)?

Comment: Start up in single-user mode (press cmd+s on startup), change password (`mount -uw / ; launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.opendirectoryd.plist ; passwd <username>`), exit (`exit`).

Comment: If you can create a new administrator user account in `System Preferences`>`Users & Groups` you can then log into that administrator and in the same system preferences User & Groups settings, select your main administrator user account in the left sidebar and press `Reset password` and it should allow you to reset it without prompting you for your old password. This may work for you, because I believe single-user mode doesn't work on the most recent macOS systems cc @JoyJin

Comment: @AVelj That will require you to enter your password to add a user

Answer (score -2):

Click in the password box and see if it pops-up with your email address. if it does select it and see if that works.  Your password is often safed with your user name which is often your email address.